# Difference between Web Application & Web Forms Application in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

What is the difference between **Web Application** & **Web Forms Application** in Visual Studio 2012?

[image]

Comment: possible related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917933/confused-between-web-application-and-web-forms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The clue is in the word 'Empty'.

The first (highlighted in your image) option is a blank project.

Subsequent options set up a Web Forms, MVC3 or MVC4 project with appropriate directory structure and a default set of pages and supporting code.

Comment: May be... but if I create a Empty Web Application, Then I cant use it as a MVC application...

Comment: Well, you could. But you would need to build it from scratch and also construct it manually. In an MVC app VS helpfully knits together elements of your application for you as you go along and generally supports you as you create your app by providing skeleton code.