# How to find out what type of web application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

related to this question. [Difference between Web Application & Web Forms Application in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184490/difference-between-web-application-web-forms-application-in-vs2012)

Now if I am presented with a solution that was created by someone else
how can I tell what type of web app was selected when the creator created it?

is there a way to tell?

[image]

Comment: Also, why do you need to know? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I wanted to clone a solution. but rather clone the full solution I wanted to start from a clean slate. so I would like to know what type of web application I should pick to achieve similar results. The reason I wanted to start from a clean slate is because the original solution has a lot of garbage that is not used and hard to understand. Ideally my solution will be simpler and documented properly.

Comment: Then you don't need to know what kind of project it used to be - you need to know what project template you should use in your _new_ solution. That's a different question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no difference between "ASP.NET Empty Web Application" and "ASP.NET Web Forms Application". The second one simply adds a bunch of stuff to the empty project, like a master page, content files, references, etc., but they're the same project type.

The different project types are the MVC projects and the "Web Site".

MVC Projects are still regular ASP.NET, but have the extra MVC stuff thrown in. If you see a "Controllers" and "Views" directory, then it's a safe bet it's an MVC project.

"Web Site"s are very different from traditional projects. Biggest hint there would probably be the lack of a .vbproj file, and the lack of .designer.vb files on each of the .aspx pages.

Answer (score -1):

A web forms application is a type of web application.

You can tell a web forms application because it will contain one or more files with the .aspx extension.

If you don't find any .aspx files, it is a web application but not a web forms application.

Comment: You can also find aspx files in MVC applications that use the classic view engine instead of Razor, or in Web Sites.